# pexpect - can't run example, kept getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spawn'

Tags: python, pexpect

I am running Python3 and been trying to run sshls.py script but always fail with:

#### AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spawn"

I tried running as:

```
python3 sshls.py
```

I even modified the script to set either env or python script but still fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

I tried with python2.7 and still get same error.

Content of script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
 
from __future__ import absolute_import
 
import pexpect
import getpass, os, traceback
def ssh_command (user, host, password, command):
     ssh_newkey = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'
     child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -l %s %s %s'%(user, host, command))
     i = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, ssh_newkey, 'password: '])
     if i == 0: # Timeout
         print('ERROR!')
         print('SSH could not login. Here is what SSH said:')
         print(child.before, child.after)
         return None
     if i == 1: # SSH does not have the public key. Just accept it.
         child.sendline ('yes')
         child.expect ('password: ')
         i = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, 'password: '])
         if i == 0: # Timeout
             print('ERROR!')
             print('SSH could not login. Here is what SSH said:')
             print(child.before, child.after)
             return None
     child.sendline(password)
     return child
 
def main ():
     host = "www.example.com"
     user = "root"
     password = "password"
     child = ssh_command (user, host, password, '/bin/ls -l')
     child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
     print(child.before)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
     try:
         main()
     except Exception as e:
         print(str(e))
         traceback.print_exc()
         os._exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks Robert Harvey for modifying my code formatting, I was just able to save the changes too but says someone already helped me updated it.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, finally got it working by copying the pexpect.py script into the same directory as where my scripts are. Weird thing was that by executing my code stand-alone in IDLE it works but not via python  unless the pexpect.py is in same directory as your script.

Answer (score 1):

see： http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#windows

Requirements
This version of Pexpect requires Python 3.3 or above, or Python 2.7.

As of version 4.0, Pexpect can be used on Windows and POSIX systems. However, pexpect.spawn and pexpect.run() are only available on POSIX, where the pty module is present in the standard library. See [Pexpect on Windows](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#windows) for more information.